# Updating procedures, packages, functions when moving from Oracle9i to Oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

I've recieved a large Oracle9i scheme, which i'am supposed to convert to Oracle11g.
Unfortunately, it uses a lot of logicaly invalid sql statements "order sibling by **LEVEL**" throughout functions, procedures and packages, which isn't declined by Oracle9i, but cause parser error in Oracle11g.

What I want to achieve, is the most simplest way to replace invalid statements without patching packages and procedures by hand, or somehow to disable parser behaviour for this error for sometime on production server, before I fix all such errors manually.

Can it be done somehow in "automatic" way?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
Ok, here is the sample of the query itself. Notice that the query has no syntax error. The difference is HOW Oracle9i and Oracle11g and higher behave while checking the validation rules of ligocal corretness.

```
select version, ord, level as lvl from
(
 select a.key, a.parent_key, a.version, a.ord from b_rds_elem a where a.dict_key = 306350
)
connect by prior key = parent_key
start with parent_key is null
order siblings by level, ord
```

This query will execute by Oracle 9i and less, and will throw error ORA-00976 in higher than 9i. Ordering siblings by level is meaningless because in hierarchical queries all nodes are already ordered with levels by default. So, 9i was more liberal for such *stupid* queries, but 11g not.

Comment: The order by doesn't look invalid in itself (thohg it [should be `siblings` rather than `sibling`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#sthref6806)). Can you edit the question to show an example - simple - query and the whole error you get?

Comment: I guess, if you know the issues at hand and a patch, you could write a parser to do individual sweeps, replacing bad for good. Not necessarily straightforward and risks introducing errors. Still, depends on the manual task and if you have a set of tests you can apply to check finished scripts for correctness. The "parser" could just be a set of shell scripts using grep and awk.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. How is your code stored - hopefully in some kind of source control? You can probably automate the checkout, edit and checkin, but only if you're looking for a specific pattern to replace, e.g. with `sed -e "s!order siblings by level,!order siblings by!"`. But you'd need to identify all possible patterns and how you do it will depend on your environment etc., and you need to be careful of introducing errors as wmorrison365 said.

Comment: Thanks to wmorrison365 and Alex Poole. I've made some searhes for different utilities and shells for this task, and SQL Developer helped me a lot. I wrote small extension shell script with the advanced search in SQLDev, and update all queries in a moment. May be it would be best, if your posted your comments as answers, so I can mark them as accepted answers for future use.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not order by level, that would muck it up. Just order by the attributes - it orders the SIBILINGS preserving the levels. Order by level would not make sense with "siblings". In 11G, it is validated and you get an error, but in 9i this gets unnoticed and destroys the levels for siblings.

Comment: Yes, I already knew it long ago before. The question is how to repair such invalid scripts globaly throughout scheme in most errorless way and with minimal effort.

Comment: apart from rewriting i dont know any easy way.